# Changing IIS URL Rewrite config location

Tags: iis, url, url-rewriting, web-config, sitecore

When used at site level, the IIS7 URL Rewrite 2 module saves its configuration in the web.config file of that site. I'm using Sitecore CMS, and best practice is to store any web.config customisations in a separate config file for ease of upgrading, staging/production setups etc.

Is there any way to specify a different config file for IIS7 redirects?

I know that application-level rewrites are stored in ApplicationHost.config, but I have several sites running on the server and would like to keep them separated.

Thanks, Adam

Answer (score 1):

In order to support this best practice you've mentioned, Sitecore implements pluggable configs, but only for the elements inside `<sitecore>` section of web.config. So, unless IIS7 URL rewrite provides some way to move its stuff to a separate config (like ASP.NET does for connectionstrings.config), I'm afraid you'll have to keep it in the main web.config file.

Sorry if I'm saying obvious things.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to use rewrite maps

```xml
<rewrite>
    <rewriteMaps configSource="rewriteMaps.config" />
</rewrite>
```

Sample rewriteMaps.config file:

```xml
<rewriteMaps>
    <rewriteMap name="CustomRewrites" defaultValue="">
        <add key="/instructions" value="/documents" />
    </rewriteMap>
</rewriteMaps>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the url rewriting config, but I have an example of moving the url mapping to a separate file:

```xml
<urlMappings configSource="config\urlMappings.config"></urlMappings>
```

And that file looks like the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<urlMappings enabled="true">
    <add url="~/somedealer" mappedUrl="/?theme=4" />
    <add url="~/someotherclient" mappedUrl="/?theme=12" />
</urlMappings>
```

I'm sure the url rewriting works the same way.

Comment: Nope. You can move out sections, but the rewrite configuration is a sectiongroup, which you cannot apply configSource to.